# Convergence in probability is induced by a distance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure

I'd like to prove the following : $X_n \overset{P}{\longmapsto} X \iff d(X_n,X) = 0$ where the distance is defined as $d(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}[\lvert X-Y\rvert \wedge 1]$

For $[\Leftarrow]$ I think we can use markov inequality to state that :

$$P(\lvert X_n -X \rvert > \varepsilon) \leq P(\lvert X_n -X \rvert > \varepsilon \wedge 1) \leq P(\lvert X_n -X \rvert\wedge 1 > \varepsilon \wedge 1) \overset{\text{Markov}}{\leq} \frac{d(X_n,X)}{\varepsilon^2} \longmapsto 0$$

But I'm stuck with $[\Rightarrow]$, in particular i'm struggling to understand the following proof found :

$$\mathbb{E}[\lvert X_n -X \rvert \wedge 1] = \int_{0}^1 P(\lvert X_n -X \rvert > t)\text{dt}  + P(\lvert X_n -X \rvert > 1)$$

And to pass the limits inside the integral on the first term we can use dominated convergence theorem and for the second term we note that goes to $0$ with $n$ by hyphotesis.

I don't why Cavalieri's principle would leave the term $P(\lvert X_n -X \rvert > 1)$ since we are using Lebesgue measure, i.e $\int_{1}^{+\infty} P(\lvert X_n -X \rvert \wedge 1 > t)\text{dt}  = P(\lvert X_n -X \rvert > 1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E(|X_n-X| \wedge 1)= E[(|X_n-X| \wedge 1) I_{|X_n-X | >1})]+E[(|X_n-X| \wedge 1) I_{|X_n-X | \leq 1})]$. The first term is $P(|X_n-X| >1$. The second term is $\int_0^{\infty} P((|X_n-X|\wedge 1) I_{|X_n-X | \leq 1} >t )dt $ But this is equal to the  integral form $0$ to $1$.